# NavigationSplitView trouble passing title to Detail View

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I'm having trouble setting up a NavigationSplit view and passing details to NavigationTitle of the Detail view.

Here's my basic View setup

```
struct SplitView: View {
    
    private let folder = xFolder.folderList
    @State var selectedFolder: xFolder?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView{
            
            List(folder,selection: $selectedFolder) {folder in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) { sideBarEntry(folder.title, folder.icon, folder.count, folder.color).tag(folder) }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .tint(.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .navigationTitle("App Name")
        }
        detail: {
           
            DetailView()
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .navigationTitle(selectedFolder?.title ?? "Hello")
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {

    @State var searchString:String = ""
    var body: some View {
        
       NavigationStack{
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Text("Hello, world!")
            }
            .padding()
            .searchable(
                text: $searchString,
                placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .automatic),
                prompt: "Search"
            )
            .toolbar(content: mainToolBarContent)
        }
    }
    
    @ToolbarContentBuilder
    func mainToolBarContent() -> some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItem(id: "View", placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
            Button(action: {}
                   ,label: {
                Image(systemName: "star" )
                    .font(.body)
            })
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

And here's the data structure

```
struct xFolder: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let title: String
    let icon: String
    let count: Int //UnreadCount
    let color: Color //tint Color
    let id = UUID()
}

extension xFolder {
    
    static var folderList: [xFolder] {
        [.init(title: "Overdue", icon: "calendar.badge.exclamationmark", count:4, color: .pink),
         .init(title: "Unsynced", icon: "exclamationmark.arrow.triangle.2.circlepath", count:2, color: .pink),
         .init(title: "Completed", icon: "archivebox", count: 1442, color: .blue),
         
        ]
    }
}

/// Sidebar List Style
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func sideBarEntry(_ title: String, _ icon: String, _ count: Int, _ color: Color ) -> some View {
        
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: icon)
            //  .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
            //  .foregroundStyle(Color("exoDynamic"), Color(.systemBackground))
                .foregroundColor(color)
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
        }
        .badge(Text("\(count)").foregroundColor(.secondary))
    }
}
```

When I select a folder/entry on the NavigationSplitView I expect the NavigationTitle to be passed to the Detail view but I don't see that happening...

[image: NavigationTitle doesn't get passed down when I select the folder]

Comment: I would think the detail view needs to be wrapped inside a `NavigationStack` or else there is no navigation bar where the title is shown.